# How to save a .docx file in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, docxtemplater

I have a firebase function that creates a word document from a template and sending it back to the client, The client is getting the buffer being sent and suppose to download it to the user as a word document.

I used `console.log()` to print the `buffer` and the data is sent to the client correctly.

But for some reason I am getting this error message when trying to open it.

[image]

firebase function called by the user:

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    const parameters = req.body.data;
    const analyzer = new Analyzer(parameters);
    analyzer.analyze();
    const docxwritter = new DocxWritter(analyzer);
    const buffer = await docxwritter.save();
    res.json({data: buffer});
  });
});
```

This is the 'save' fucntion of the docxwritter class (Also I am using 'docxtemplater' libary).

```
async save() {
    this.doc.setData(this.context);

    // Perform the templating process
    this.doc.render();

    // Get the generated DOCX content as a buffer
    const docxBuffer = await this.doc.getZip()
        .generate({type: "nodebuffer"});
    
    return docxBuffer;
  }
```

And this is how I am saving the file in the client side:

```
 const functions = getFunctions();
 const callableFunction = httpsCallable(functions, 'test');
    
 callableFunction(parameters).then((res) => {
     const wordDocumentBuffer = res.data.data;
            
     const wordDocumentBlob = new Blob([wordDocumentBuffer]);
     const wordDocumentUrl = URL.createObjectURL(wordDocumentBlob);
        
     const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
     downloadLink.href = wordDocumentUrl;
     downloadLink.download = 'word-document.docx';
     document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        
     downloadLink.click();
 }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
 });
```

I used `console.log` to print the `buffer` and the `buffer.length` that I am getting from the `docxwritter.save()` function to check if the problem is with the docx document creation. but the output I got seems to be correct:

```
docxBuffer length: 276528

docxBuffer:  <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 21 00 1e 91 1a b7 4e 02 00 00 4e 02 00 00 0b 00 00 00 5f 72 65 6c 73 2f 2e 72 65 6c 73 3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 ... 276478 more bytes>
```

also I run it with a `test.js` file to try save it locally using only the classes I wrote without the front-end and the file was saved correctly and looked good when I opened it.

**So I am assuming that the problem is in the client side when trying to save the file in React.**

**Does anyone spotted what I am missing and what is the problem in my code?**

**Thank you.**

Comment: Don't assume: test. What does your dev tools `network` tab say? Does it show the full data being transmitted? Does the client code get that full length data? I.e. what is the data it has _before_ it tries to turn it into a download link?

Comment: File is a type of Blob no need to make a Blob then a File, just use the Blob or just the File

Comment: Share the definition for getFunctions() and httpsCallable()

Comment: the getFunctions and https callable are firebase functions: import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

Comment: I checked what the client is getting and it getting a full length buffer, but it was in a dictionary so that was the problem, now after using the data there a a bigger word file but I can not open it still, So the problem is must be in the way I download the file

Comment: I updated my question please consider checking it out, if any more code is missing please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your `save()` method is `async`, so you have to call it the right way, like so:

```
const buffer = await docxwritter.save();
```

As a consequence, your arrow function needs to be async as well, (and maybe more code, that you haven‘t posted):

```
cors(req, res, async () => {
    const parameters = req.body.data;
    const analyzer = new Analyzer(parameters);
    analyzer.analyze();
    const docxwritter = new DocxWritter(analyzer);
    const buffer = await docxwritter.save();
    res.json({data: buffer});
  });
```

Comment: I updated my question please consider checking it out, if any more code is missing please let me know.

Comment: I believe you pretty much solved it now. I am not familiar with the way you process the Word document buffer on the client side. It looks like it is breaking there. Have you also tried  something like https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js to produce the actual file?